# Adding RestAPI response to MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

```
$cn = curl_init();
$url = 'https://URL';

curl_setopt($cn, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($cn, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

$output = curl_exec($cn);

$aOutput = json_decode($output, TRUE);
//var_dump($aOutput);
$curl_error = curl_error($cn);
print_r($curl_error);

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
foreach($aOutput as $key => $data) {
    var_dump($key['average_price']);
//  var_dump($data[$key]["Average_Price"]);
//  $sql = "INSERT INTO Market('type_id', 'average_price', 'adjusted_price')
//      VALUES ($data);";
    }  
  array(10763) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["average_price"]=>
    float(381907.23)
    ["adjusted_price"]=>
    float(383184.18)
    ["type_id"]=>
    int(32772)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["average_price"]=>
    float(54090.07)
    ["adjusted_price"]=>
    float(57340.16)
    ["type_id"]=>
    int(32774)
  }
```

I am attempting to add this entire multidimensional array to my database.  The main thing I am having trouble with is the foreach loop.

I have tried $array[$key][$column], and many other ways but I only get NULL when dumping the variable.

I have attempted, $key['average_price'] etc still returns null.

Comment: Inside your foreach, `$key['average_price']` and so forth should work just fine

Comment: what structure of your `$aOutput`? I suggest you need to get data from `$data['average_price']` instead of `$key`, which is scalar, I guess. Your loop represents every item of `$aOutput` as `$key` and `$data`, where `$key` is an array index (in this partucular case) and `$data` is a hash itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting $key and $data muddled up.

Easiest if you annotate it out:

If your $aOutput array is

```
array(10763) {
    [0]=>
        array(3) {
           ["average_price"]=>float(381907.23)
           ["adjusted_price"]=>float(383184.18)
           ["type_id"]=>int(32772)
        }
   [1]=>
       array(3) {
           ["average_price"]=>float(54090.07)
           ["adjusted_price"]=>float(57340.16)
           ["type_id"]=>int(32774)
       }
    ....
```

then

```
foreach($aOutput as $key => $data) {
    // $key = 0
    // $data = array(3) {
           ["average_price"]=>float(381907.23)
           ["adjusted_price"]=>float(383184.18)
           ["type_id"]=>int(32772)
        }
    // So what you want is $data['average_price']
```

You can simplify this by not even using hte key, just do

```
foreach($aOutput as $data) {
    // $data = array(3) {
           ["average_price"]=>float(381907.23)
           ["adjusted_price"]=>float(383184.18)
           ["type_id"]=>int(32772)
        }
    // So what you want is $data['average_price']
```